# I need to write a python program to enter a telephone number as letters and then output the corresponding telephone number in digits

Tags: python

> As the title says I need help with the code as I can't understand what
> other code I could write, per se I need
> instructions exactly on how to write the following code:
>
> Using letters as the telephone number is frequently used. So, for
> instance the words GOT MILK can be converted to the phone number
> 468-6455.
>
> Write a Python program that asks the user to enter a telephone number
> as letters and then outputs the corresponding telephone number in
> digits.
>
> The program should output the '-' after the third digit. The program
> should accept both upper- and lower-case letters, and spaces.

```
My Code:

input("Enter the telephone number as letters: ")
numbers = [('abc',2), ('def',3), ('ghi',4), ('jkl',5), ('mno',6), ('pqrs',7), ('tuv',8), ('wxyz',9)]
phone = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary here,

```
d = {'a': '2', 'b': '2', 'c': '2', 'd': '3', 'e': '3', 'f': '3', 'g': '4', 'h': '4', 'i': '4', 'j': '5', 'k': '5', 'l': '5', 'm': '6', 'n': '6', 'o': '6', 'p': '7', 'q': '7', 'r': '7', 's': '7', 't': '8', 'u': '8', 'v': '8', 'w': '9', 'x': '9', 'y': '9', 'z': '9'}

def convert(s):
    r = ''.join(d.get(i, '') for i in s.lower())
    return '{}-{}'.format(r[:3], r[3:])

print(convert('GOT MILK'))
# '468-6455'
```

Comment: In the example given by the OP the fourth letter maps to space so it inserts the "-". Should we assume the fourth character is always a space so that we get a "-" after the third digit? I mean we can add a - after the third digit if the fourth character is not a space to match the rule

Comment: @Jib I didn't see that point in the question, thanks for the mention. Updated my answer.

Comment: could the code be edited to an easier understanding because I am a beginner in python and I don't understand code def convert(s):
    r = ''.join(d.get(i, '') for i in s.lower())
    return '{}-{}'.format(r[:3], r[3:])

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary for conversion.

```
numbers={'a':'2','b':'2','c':'2','d':'3','e':'3','f':'3','g':'4','h':'4','i':'4','j':'5','k':'5','l':'5','m':'6','n':'6',
         'o':'6','p':'7','q':'7','r':'7','s':'7','t':'8','u':'8','v':'8','w':'9','x':'9','y':'9','z':'9'}



phone = ''

for l in input("Enter the telephone number as letters: "):
    phone += numbers[l]
```

The above code have a predefined key value pairs. Then at the beginning of the loop, it asks the user to input and then it converts the user input to an iterator and assign each letter of the input to the variable `l`, and then concatenate to the empty `phone` variable. At the end of the loop, all the characters, would be mapped to a digit.

Just note that the user input should be exactly similar to the keys in the `number` variable. Other than those keys, the program raises and error. In the other suggested answer, the complexity comes from handling several common scenarios that may arise such as if the user input `'A'` instead of `'a'` and so on.

Comment: I got the following python error:                                                                                         phone += numbers[l]
KeyError: ' '   I need to able to be able to output any letters to a number

Comment: The variable numbers is a hash table structure. In the above case, it maps the letter to the associated key. For example `{'a':'2'}`, `'a'` is the key and the associated value is `'2'`. You need to update the variable numbers based on your need for converting the user input to your desired output.